# Origin doesnt follow physics Simulation

Tags: physics

Trying to make the camera always face a cloth Simulation. The problem is the Origin doesnt move with the Simulation and by that the camera always looks to where the Origin was at the start of the physics animation. 
Im using the "Track to" Constraint on the Camera.

Here is a GIF showing the exact problem: https://gyazo.com/fffd446c202453b0a33f5ac09150a6bd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertex parent an *empty* to a single vertex somewhere near the center of the cloth object. Then put a *Damped Track* constraint on the camera and point it to the empty. It would appear that physics simulations respect vertex parenting relationships. You don't even have to bake the simulation first to see the results.